# Access 2013 - "Query too complex" error when searching on 18 fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using Access for searching in the database using multiple (around 18) criteria. All those criteria need to be combined to deliver the right results. The search query is being evaluated as being too complex.

In the query, I use the filled in search fields (the temporary variables) to find the contacts that match all search fields.

That query looks as follows:

```
SELECT 
      Contacts.ID, 
      Contacts.[Naam Contact], 
      Contacts.Adresgegevens, 
      Nz([Contacts]![Type Opleiding]) AS [Type opleiding], 
      Contacts.OplGetal, 
      Contacts.DataCV, 
      Nz([Contacts]![Datum Sollicitatie],
      DateSerial(1901,1,1)) AS [Datum Sollicitatie], 
      Contacts.LaatstGewijzigd, 
      Contacts.Voornaam, 
      Contacts.Achternaam, 
      Contacts.Medewerker, 
      Contacts.Zoektermen, 
      Contacts.Woonplaats, 
      Contacts.Geboortejaar, 
      Contacts.[A], 
      Contacts.[B], 
      Contacts.[C], 
      Contacts.D, 
      Contacts.E, 
      Contacts.Overig, 
      Year(Now())-[Geboortejaar]-1 & "/" & Year(Now())-[Geboortejaar] AS Leeftijd, 
      Contacts.BinnengekomenBij, 
      Contacts.Categorie, 
      Contacts.BinnenBuiten
   FROM 
      Contacts
   WHERE 
          Contacts.[Naam Contact] Like "*" & TempVars!tmpNaam & "*"
      And Contacts.Adresgegevens Like "*" & TempVars!tmpAdres & "*"
      And Nz(Contacts![Type Opleiding]) Like "*" & TempVars!tmpOpleiding & "*"
      And Contacts.OplGetal > TempVars!tmpHGO-1
      And Nz(Contacts![Datum Sollicitatie],DateSerial(1901,1,1)) > DateValue(TempVars!tmpDatumSol) 
      And (   TempVars!tmpBiBu = Contacts.BinnenBuiten 
           Or TempVars!tmpBiBu = "Maakt niet uit" ) 
      And (TempVars!tmpOP=No Or Contacts.[A]=Yes)
      And (TempVars!tmpSP=No Or Contacts.[B]=Yes)
      And (TempVars!tmpSS=No Or Contacts.[C]=Yes)
      And (TempVars!tmpINS=No Or Contacts.D=Yes)
      And (TempVars!tmpE=No Or Contacts.E=Yes)
      And (TempVars!tmpOverig=No Or Contacts.Overig=Yes)
      And (TempVars!tmpMed=No Or Contacts.Medewerker=Yes)
      And (Nz(Contacts.BinnengekomenBij) Like "*" & TempVars!tmpBin & "*"
      And (TempVars!tmpCat=Contacts.Categorie Or TempVars!tmpCat="Beide")
```

How can I make this query smarter and less complex?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Microsoft has some suggestions to solve this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103429 ; although they say 'Avoid stacked query objects', you could to try creating a first level query that filters only on any key fields you have (thus removing them from this query), then use that query as input to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my problem!
The complexity came from all the checkboxes that I checked, e.g.:

```
(TempVars!tmpE=No Or Contacts.E=Yes)
```

Because of the combination of all those checkboxes, the query finally looked something like this:
http://www.blueclaw-db.com/accessquerysql/complex_query.gif

The solution was to put everything in VBA-code and build the query dynamically. Now a checkbox is included in the query (appended to the query) only if it is checked. A code snippet regarding checkbox E:

```
If Me.checkboxE = True Then
    strSQL = strSQL + "And Contacts.E=Yes "
End If
```

This removed the complexity from the query and everything runs smoothly now!

Answer (score 0):

The way I used to solve these kinds of errors is to start by putting most of the selected fields in comments including inside the WHERE clause, then one by one I added one, and ran the query. Eventually you'll get to the one that is causing the complex result. If my memory serves me correctly, I think it's caused by the Nz function.